# Querying multiple graphs with aggregate Count and graph in results

Tags: sparql, fuseki, named-graphs

Is it possible to count the occurrences of triples in multiple named graphs and return the results as rows in a table? Such as:

```
   ?g    ?count  ?sequence_count
-------- ------- ---------------
 graph1    54          54
 graph2    120         80
```

Here is the query that I tried.

```
SELECT ?g ?count ?sequence_count     
    FROM NAMED <graph1>
    FROM NAMED <graph2>
WHERE {
    { 
       select (COUNT(?identifier) as ?count) (COUNT(?sequence) as ?sequence_count) 
       WHERE { GRAPH ?g { 
           ?identifier a <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Resource> . 
           OPTIONAL { ?identifier <urn:sequence> ?sequence } 
       } }
    }
}
```

But the results were:

```
   ?g    ?count  ?sequence_count
-------- ------- ---------------
           174          134
```

I'm trying to avoid having to write out:

```
select ?count_graph1 ?sequence_count_graph1 ?count_graph2 ...
```

as there could be hundreds of graphs to query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the query is really close.  Just move the `SELECT` inside of the graph statement - basically stating 'for each graph, find these aggregate values'.  Second, if any of the `?identifier` matches have multiple values, the count for `?identifier` will have duplicates, so `DISTINCT` results are necessary.  Try the following:

```
SELECT *
  FROM NAMED <graph1>
  FROM NAMED <graph2>
WHERE {
   GRAPH ?g {
      SELECT (COUNT(DISTINCT ?identifier) as ?count) (COUNT(?sequence) as ?sequence_count)
      WHERE {
         ?identifier a <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Resource> . 
         OPTIONAL { ?identifier <urn:sequence> ?sequence }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: so that gives me a count of ?identifiers in all graphs combined. What I'm looking for is a count of ?identifiers in each individual graph. so graph1 would have a count(?identifiers), graph2 would have a count(?identifiers).

Comment: In that case I think your original query was really close.  See the amended response.